# How to make a Div with Images responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a DIV with some images inside responsive.

```css
 #copyright-wrap {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px #888;
   color: #444;
   margin-top: 60px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-left: 2px;
   padding: 25px 20px 15px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #copyright-text {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 #copyright-wrap a {
   color: #444;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 #copyright-text img {
   height: 85px;
   margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="copyright-wrap">
  <div id="copyright-text">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="logo1-copy.png" alt="logo1 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-778" />
    </a>
    <a href="/town-view-cairo/">
      <img src="logo2-copy.png" alt="logo2 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-779" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried giving the container `min-width` and `max-width` but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make images to be responsive in a div. If that so you need to give width:100% in css for the img to make them responsive

Comment: img {
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: auto\9; /*ie8*/
}

Comment: By giving height:auto and max-width:100%, it was showing actual image size.. Now all the images are in single line.. I want it to go each line after screen reach 400px around ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I don't know exactly what it is you require, but here's something for you anyway.

```css
#copyright-wrap {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #888;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#copyright-wrap a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
#copyright-text img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div id="copyright-wrap">
  <div id="copyright-text">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/cdcdcd" alt="logo1 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-778" />
    </a>
    <a href="/town-view-cairo/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/cdcdcd" alt="logo2 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-779" />
    </a>
    <a href="/sunset-pearl-sahl-hasheesh/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/cdcdcd" alt="logo3 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-780" />
    </a>
    <a href="/vacation-club/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/cdcdcd" alt="logo4 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-781" />
    </a>
    <a href="/paradise-gardens-sahl-hasheesh/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/cdcdcd" alt="logo5 copy" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-782" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time.. See by increasing the screen, last image coming down and incresing the screen more other image was coming down beside to last image.. at last in 2 2 columns images are aligning, and last forming the images in 1 column.. What I am trying to make is, all the images should be in one line.. by increasing screen all the images should form in 2 columns and at last they should form in 1 column..

Comment: I think your are using the word increasing instead of decreasing.. is it right?

Comment: Which device you what to make two column you just add a media query  and add property to #copyright-wrap a selector width: 48%; and margin: 1%;

Comment: I am looking for iPAD, iPhone5S... Can you please give me syntax for media query..